# Given a quadratic equation, find a value of a such that the quadratic equation would have one root less than -1 and another greater than 1.

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I was given this problem:

> For what values of $a$ is one of the roots of the equation $$(a^2+a+1)x^2+(2a−3)x+(a−5)=0$$ greater than 1, while the other one is smaller than $1$?

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Can someone possibly help me solve this problem so I can learn how to solve these types of problems?

Comment: Can you find the roots of this equation using the quadratic formula? The answer will depend upon $a$ of course, but you can use the answer to investigate the sizes of the roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It means this polynomial has two real roots and that $1$ separates the roots.

- The discriminant $\Delta=(2a-3)^2-4(a^2+a+1)(a-5)>0$,
- Under this hypothesis, there is a high-school theorem on the separation of roots:

> Let $p(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial  with two real roots and $\alpha$ be a real number. Then $\alpha$ separates the roots of $p(x)$ if and only if $p(\alpha)$ and  the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ have opposite signs.

Here, the leading coefficient is $a^2+a+1$, which is always positive (its roots are the complex cubic roots of unity). So the separating condition is merely
$$p(1)=a^2+a+1+2a-3+a-5=a^2+4a-7 <0. $$
Note that if $p(1)<0$, the quadratic polynomial necessarily has tow real roots;, so the first condition is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Let $f(x)=(a^2+a+1)x^2+(2a−3)x+a−5.$

Thus, since $$a^2+a+1=\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}>0,$$  we need to solve the following inequality: $$f(1)<0.$$